# updating a part/the date of the URL in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Basically, I haven't done much of excel formulation so this is new to me. I have an excel file which has a few hundreds of URL in it. now, most of these URL's are a search from different websites which include the dates in them. for example:

https://www.ft.com/search?q=investment&dateTo=2018-11-21&dateFrom=2018-11-21&sort=date

so the q=investment is what I'm searching which is static but the part To=2018-11-21&dateFrom=2018-11-21 depends on the date of everytime I open the file. I wonder if there is a way to formulate this URL so everytime I open the file, the dateTo=2018-11-21, and dateFrom=2018-11-21 gets updated by itself to todays date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the original URLs are in column `B`, and you put today's date `=TODAY()` in cell `A1`, you then put the following formula in cell `C1` :
`=SUBSTITUTE(B1;"2018-11-21";TEXT($A$1;"yyyy-mm-dd"))`
And copy down as far as needed.

I hard coded the `"2018-11-21"` old date in the formula, but it would of course be easier to re-use if you put the old date in eg. `A2` as a text string (very important, not as a date!)

If you want to have hyperlinks as output, just wrap with `HYPERLINK()` function:
`=HYPERLINK(SUBSTITUTE(B1;"2018-11-21";TEXT($A$1;"yyyy-mm-dd")))`

Comment: A1: =TODAY()
B1: my url
C1: =SUBSTITUTE(B1;"2018-11-21";TEXT($A$1;"yyyy-mm-dd"))

it doesn't work!

Comment: Did you change the formula delimiter? In some countries you have to change the ; (semicolon) with , (comma).

Comment: And please note that with the example in your question, running this **today** in Excel no changes will be made, as it is today 2018-11-21 ...

Comment: the comma did the trick, thanks a lot but since its a formula, the result is not a URL. I need to find a way to make it to a URL. Is there a trick for that as well or i have to copy past them ?

Comment: @Ali Very easy, just wrap in `HYPERLINK()` function. I updated my answer with this.